# Efficient way to merge two DB backed entities Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

Please link me if same question has been answered earlier.Here is details of my problem.
I have a ShoppingCart object in database with following structure

```
ShoppingCart{

 Set<ShoppingCartItem> lineItems 

}

ShoppingCartItem{
Set<ShoppingCartAttributeItem> attributes 
}

ShoppingCartAttributeItem{
// attributes
}
```

All above entities are DB backed entries in my Hibernate application.I need to merge 2 different instances of `ShoppingCart` at given conditions

1. User added some products to his cart.
2. After Adding product , user decided to login to system

There are cases when user has already a `ShoppingCart`, so moment he logged in to system . I need to merge his `ShoppingCart` with Current Session cart.

I can fetch both `ShoppingCart` from the DB

1. Fetch Cart associated with the current logged in user.
2. Fetch `ShoppingCart` associated with user before login

In Short, I need to merge `lineItems` of both the ShoppingCart.I am not sure how best I can do this?
Is there any efficient way to merge those `lineItems` or I need to create them one by one.?

Answer (score 0):

Given the amout of items to expect in a shopping cart, I wouldn't worry too much about efficiency. There is usually nothing wrong with copying the items over in a loop.

While it may be possible to come up with some form of UPDATE statement that does your merge, it probably just brings in needless complexity. (Realistically, you would add further logic anyway, like eliminating duplicates...)